# How to resolve kafka multiple broker edge case?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, amazon-sqs, spring-kafka

I have a Java project which reads particular messages from AWS SQS, parses the message and publishes it to Kafka. I have made the project self healing. If a Kafka connection is lost, I log the following message:

```
{"timestamp":"2021-03-01T16:31:30.306Z","logger":"org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient","level":"WARN","class":"org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient","method":"processDisconnection","file":"NetworkClient.java","line":671,"thread":"kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1","message":"[Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available."}
```

If I re-establish the Kafka connection, the project is able to reconnect to Kafka and continue to consume from SQS and publish to Kafka as required. That is when I only have 1 Kafka broker. I've identified an edge case, I'm trying to figure out how to manage. Suppose I have Kafka brokers A and B. Suppose A is the leader. The edge case is the following: If a Kafka connection is lost and then recovered by recovering Kafka broker B and but not A, the project is not able to connect and publish to Kafka as required. It keeps searching for broker A. Once the Kafka broker A is brought back, where Kafka broker B is already connected, the Kafka connection cannot be established properly and publishing to Kafka does not work as expected.

Might anyone be familiar with such an edge case? Is it possible to change the priority of Kafka brokers within a project? Or might anyone have other suggestions how to resolve this edge case?

Comment: Your premise seems to be off-base. This is what replication is for. Typically, you will have an odd number of brokers, with topics/partitions distributed across those brokers with a replication factor of at least 2. Then, you can survive an outage of one broker. There is no such thing as connecting to broker A. The client initially connects to one of the brokers and uses the actual broker topology returned by that broker to actually connect to the leaders of each partition as needed.

Comment: But there is a leader Kafka broker, is there not? My intention here is to come up with a self-healing approach for when there are multiple brokers and the leader is not available. Is that possible? For instance, in the case you're explaining, what happens if one broker is available but the leader is not able to connect?

Comment: No; a leader is selected for each partition of a topic, not the overall cluster; given 3 brokers and 3 replicas and a topic with 3 partitions and min. insync replicas set to 2, you can always write to each partition. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_min.insync.replicas When you lose a broker, the leader becomes the other in-sync replica.